# Nuget + Ninject + My site won't compile because of wrong version?

Tags: dll, reference, ninject, conflict, nuget

I tried to update my ninject stuff to the newest version and now I get this error

```
Error   133 Assembly 'Ninject.Web.Mvc, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' uses 'Ninject, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Ninject, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7'
```

I also tried deleting and reinstall the ninject .dlls but same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the References of your project in Visual Studio. Look for the Ninject reference and right-click it. In the properties grid you should be able to see its version. It's probably 2.0.0.0. Try to delete this version and then add a reference to the newest version 2.2.0.0.

Comment: So I went to the .dll and hit F4(properties) and it says Version 2.0.0. So I deleted it and tryied to reinstall it. Still same thing 2.0.0. I then went to ninjects site and downloaded the newest version and added myself. I get still 2.0.0. I make a new mvc application and add it and the version v2.2.2. So I don't know what is going on.

Comment: I know what it is: close VS. Now delete the bin and object folders of your site project. Open VS and add the reference again for the new DLL. VS keeps the reference to the old DLL that's is in the bin folder. You can see the path in the properties grid. Even when you add a reference to the new DLL it still points to the old one in the bin folder. Hope this solves your problem.